# Best reverse proxy for IIS 6?

Tags: iis, tomcat, iis-6, reverse-proxy

I want to set up a reverse proxy from one of our intranet IIS sites to point to another tomcat server. Eg, i want the user to browse to 'http://our-iis-server/friendly-url' and for it to reverse proxy to 'http://our-tomcat-server/ugly-url'.

What would be the best solution for this? I've narrowed it down to three options:

- http://www.managedfusion.com/products/url-rewriter/documentation.aspx
- http://www.isapirewrite.com/
- http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF

Also, can these tools rewrite the links in the html? Eg, if the tomcat server's html has something like 'a href = http://our-tomcat-server/ugly-url/product/widget' i would need it to change to 'a href = http://our-iis-server/friendly-url/product/widget'

Thanks in advance. All good answers will be voted for!!!

Comment: Found this: http://www.addedbytes.com/apache/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Amusingly in the end, a simple frameset did everything we needed.

Comment: whatever you do DONT write your own reverse proxy.. it always ends in tears.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIRF is good and free. <strike>However, it's not a reverse proxy - *not yet anyway*</strike>. [as of March 2010, IIRF can act as a Reverse Proxy] It's the equivalent of Apache's mod`_`rewrite, and you need mod`_`proxy.

It looks like Helicon ISAPI Rewrite 3.0 supports proxying as well as URL rewriting.

Free options include [Apache on Windows](http://www.ricocheting.com/server/apache.html), or you can also run Squid as a proxy server.  The canonical Microsoft answer is [ISA Server](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/edgesecurity/isaserver/en/us/default.aspx).

Comment: Cheeso appears to be the IIRF author, and the "not yet anyway" comment that he added hopefully means that it's something that's on his radar!

Comment: IIRF now acts as a Reverse Proxy.